# Find 'x' satisfying equation $4^{\log_{10} {x+1}} - 6^{\log_{10} x} - 2.3^{\log_{10} {x^2 +2}}$ = 0

Tags: logarithms

The question is from logs

Find 'x' satisfying equation $4^{\log_{10} {x+1}} - 6^{\log_{10} x} - 2.3^{\log_{10} {x^2 +2}}$ = 0

I've tried to solve it. I was trying to convert base `10` of logs to respective numbers. like 4 for first one 6 for second one and 2.3 for third one. I thought that I'll be able to move those logs from powers. But I'm not able to figure how I convert them .

Please explain I can solve it. And Please solve it like a class 11th student.

Comment: Maybe you could add some parentheses to make it clearer, for example, if the first term is $4^{\log_{10}(x+1)}$ or $4^{(\log_{10}x)+1}$? Anyway, in the latter case you can do
$$4^{(\log_{10}x)+1}=4\cdot 4^{\log_{10}x}=4\cdot\left(10^{\log_{10}4}\right)^{\log_{10}x}=4\cdot\left(10^{\log_{10}x}\right)^{\log_{10}4}=4x^{\log_{10}4}$$
but I'm not sure how helpful this is.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The above expression is reducible to:

$$4\times 2^{2\log(x)} - 6^{\log(x)} - 18 \times 3^{2 \log(x)} = 0$$

Now let $ 2^{\log(x)} = a$ and $3^{\log(x)} = b$.

The above expression then becomes:

$$4a^2-ab-18b^2 = 0$$

Now factorize and solve for $x$!

Comment: Please explain, how did you solved it to $18 × 3^{2\log(x)}$

Comment: $2\times 3^2 \times 3^{\log(x^2)} = 2\times3^{\log(x^2) +2}$

Comment: Okay I got it. Maybe you didn't noticed it. That isn't multiply in between 2.3 ,its decimal.

Comment: That's highly unlikely that it's a decimal. Solve it assuming $\times$ and see if you get the answer given?

Comment: :( Its really hard to factorize it.

Comment: Answer given in sheet is $x = 1/100$

Comment: $4a^2-9ab + 8ab -18b^2 = 0$

Comment: Thank you. Well, answer didn't matched. But I learned alot.

Comment: Please try it taking as decimal.

Comment: I am getting $x= 1/100$. The answer matches

Comment: Let me check I might have did some mistake

Comment: Thank you again. You're great.  I solved it.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: Note that

$$
\text{log}_{10}(x) = \frac{\text{log}_{a}(x)}{\text{log}_{a}(10)}
$$

for any $a>0$. You could use this fact to your advantage by doing:

$$
a^{\text{log}_{10}(x)} = a^\frac{{\text{log}_{a}(x)}}{\text{log}_a(10)} = \left( a^{\text{log}_{a}(x)}\right)^{\frac{1}{\text{log}_a(10)}} = x^{\frac{1}{\text{log}_a(10)}}
$$

Answer (score 0):

Hint.

Calling

$$
a=2^{\log_{10}x}\\
b=3^{\log_{10}x}
$$

we have

$$
2^2a^2-a b-2\cdot 3^2b^2=(4a-9b)(a+2b) = 0
$$

Comment: Maybe you didn't saw it properly its isn't 2⋅3, its 2.3. Decimal is in between.